# Heap Dump On Java 1.4.1

Tags: jvm, solaris, heap-dump, jdk1.4

is there anyway that I can take a heap dump using java 1.4.1 on Solaris 9?

I'm using a very old application server and java version and would like to take a heap dump.
I'm gonna use it on production so hprof may not be an option. Is there any tools that I could install ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There [seem to be bugs](http://performance.netbeans.org/articles/hat-howto/) with HPROF for JDKs 1.4 and 1.4.1

> Warning: JDK 1.4 and JDK 1.4.1 contains a bug in hprof. You cannot use these versions with HAT.

so you may consider upgrading to latest update from JDK 1.4.2

This way you could use [backported `jmap` for Solaris](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/ReleaseNotes.html#142_09) to take a heap dump like described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/125451/7149).